# Assign SQL rows unique pages

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

sorry if this is a bit vague although I really don't know how to explain this one.

Basically I already have a listing page that lists all of the rows in my database into a html template that lists each row into an eCommerce style category page using PHP.

I am using this code for the listing page using PDO:

```
<?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '
        <div class="listing-container">
          <h3 class="model-listing-title clearfix">'.$row["Make"].' '.$row["Model"].' '.$row["Variant"].'</h3>
          <h3 class="price-listing">£'.number_format($row['Price']).'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-container-spec">
         <img src="'.(explode(',', $row["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" class="stock-img-finder"/>
          <div class="ul-listing-container">
            <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
              <li class="diesel-svg list-svg">'.$row["FuelType"].'</li>
              <li class="saloon-svg list-svg">'.$row["Bodytype"].'</li>
              <li class="gear-svg list-svg">'.$row["Transmission"].'</li>
              <li class="color-svg list-svg">'.$row["Colour"].'</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul other-specs-ul h4-style">
            <li>Mileage: '.number_format($row["Mileage"]).'</li>
            <li>Engine size: '.$row["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
          </ul>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style checked-btn hover-listing-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> History checked 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style more-details-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> More details 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style test-drive-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="test-drive-glyph"></span> Test drive 
          </button>
          <h4 class="h4-style listing-photos-count"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> 5 More photos</h4>
        </div>
          ';
      } ?>
      </div>
```

Now what I want to do is create a page for each of the SQL rows however I am unsure how I can do this, just like an eBay product page really.

My main question is what method could I do to create individual pages that are dedicated to each SQL row?

If anyone could shed a bit of light on this for me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for pagination?

Comment: No, for example let's say you search for something on eBay and you get the lists of products, if you click on one of the products it takes you to that products dedicated page, that's what I am trying to develop.

Comment: Just create a separate php page and href to that.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing you can extract data from a page to another using `$_POST['name-of-your-element']`, I would say to do something like this :

1. Creating a php page dedicated to display information of one specific row
2. Putting some $_POST['...'] call to display the exact data

To do this, instead of just displaying your row in your actual page, you should create form for each row, and then adding a submit button for each row which will launch the "display row page" with the correct information. I would see something like this for each row :

```
<form method = "post" action = "displayData_Make.php">
    <div id = "Make" name = "Make">
        Make : <?php echo $row['Make'] ?>
    </div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "more information..." />
</form>
```

Then in you "displayData_Make.php" receive your information and display them like you want :

```
<?php 
    $info = $_POST['Make'];

    // Do what you want with this data
    // Display, etc...
?>

<!-- 
    Some html code
-->
```